# PostgreSQL-No suitable driver found for JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, jdbc

I am trying to make an INSERT to my database this way:

```
package org.gradle.demo;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

@WebServlet(name = "HelloServlet", urlPatterns = {"register"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private Connection conn;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        try {
            conn = DBUtils.initializeSqlConnection();
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            int count = statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO users (username, pass) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "')");
            System.out.println(count);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQL Exception trying to insert new user");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        request.setAttribute("username", username);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("loginsucces.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

I am using Gradle with this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.2'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.19.0'
    testCompile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '2.2.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.13.0'
}
```

And also I have tested my connection in another class doing a SELECT and it connects perfectly, but as soon as I try to make an INSERT it throws the:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/training_log
```

Comment: Can you check your JAR/WAR which you are running to see if the Postgres driver JAR made it there?

Comment: is the port missing from the connection string `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/training_log`?

Comment: @S.K. don't think so because I can reach the database succesfully doing a SELECT.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didn't downloaded the driver JAR, isn't it enough to declare the dependency in Gradle?

Comment: Is this a single project setup or do you have multiple projects with possibly different dependencies?

Comment: Should the postgres dependency be runtime instead of compile time?

Comment: @S.K. I changed the dependency to runtime and is still failing.

Comment: @dpr A single project

Comment: And the other class you used to test the SELECT statement is a servlet as well?

Comment: @dpr No, I tested it in a main method.

Comment: How do you run your project? Which servlet container, how do you deploy the project to the container, ...

Comment: @dpr I use gretty in order to test my project. Also I use Tomcat so I simply go to localhost port 8080.

Comment: So, you run `gradle war` and manually copy the war file to Tomcat's webapps folder? Please validate the content of your war file by extracting it using a standard zip tool (7zip for example) and check if the postgres jar is contained under WEB-INF\lib.

Comment: @dpr I checked it and it is contained.

Comment: If you deploy a JDBC driver within your war, then you need to explicitly load the driver. See the linked duplicate.